# A subclass of log-concave functions satifying a sum inequality

Tags: convexity, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, co.combinatorics

Suppose $f:[0,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$ is continuous and for all positive integers $m$ and real $x\geq0$, $\alpha,\beta>0$:
$$
\sum\limits_{k+n=m}[f(x+\alpha+k)f(x+\beta+n)-f(x+k)f(x+\alpha+\beta+n)]\geq0.
$$
Is anything known about this class of functions?  If $m=0$ we have
$$
f(x+\alpha)f(x+\beta)-f(x)f(x+\alpha+\beta)\geq0
$$
which is equivalent to log-concavity of $f$.  Similar question about functions satisfying
$$
\sum\limits_{k+n=m}\binom{m}{k}[f(x+\alpha+k)f(x+\beta+n)-f(x+k)f(x+\alpha+\beta+n)]\geq0.
$$
Is there a reasonably simple sufficient condition on $f$ so that it satisfiesthe above inequalities?